# how to read line 17 only from text file using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have to write a batch script where i have to read only the contents from line 17 and save it to a variable.I used skip to eliminate the first 16 lines but i am clueless of how to eliminate the last 5 rows ie from line 18 to line 22.
Please find my piece of code below:

```
for /f "skip=16" %%G IN (ABCD.txt) DO set "variable=%%G"
```

Could someone please suggest me how to read the contents only from line 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `GOTO` to leave the FOR-loop.

```
for /f "skip=16" %%G IN (ABCD.txt) DO (
   set "variable=%%G"
   goto :LeaveLoop
)
:LeaveLoop
```